# Is there a way to test Android, iPhone push notification without having one?

Tags: iphone, android, testing, push, push-notification

I need to create a push notification webservice for Android & iPhone, but I actually own an Iphone only, I'd like to be able to test on my machine the push notification.

I don't know anything to mobile device or development.

Answer (score 3):

In order to push messages to Android using the Google Cloud to Device messaging (C2DM) requires an application on the device which has registered to the C2DM servers to receive push notifications. AFAIK, you cannot do a generic push (using C2DM) which will be received by all applications.
For more info on C2DM you can look at the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) and a good article can be found [here](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  It gives you the basic stuff you need to get up and running.

If you want a virtual machine, you can set one up using [this guide](http://www.taranfx.com/how-to-run-google-android-in-virtualbox-vmware-on-netbooks#axzz1IvQ14065).  I set this up and it was pretty painless. I don't know how current it is, but it will at least get you something to work with.